# Hints for proving $\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove the following exercise from a textbook:

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m < n$. Prove directly that for $k = 2, \dots, n$ the inequaity

$$\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}$$

holds.

My work so far:

I know that you could probably solve this using induction, but this is not how it's intended to be done. So I want to ask for hints that doesn't involve using induction.

Since $m < n$, it follows
$$\forall \alpha < k: m - \alpha < n - \alpha$$

This implies 
$$\prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (m - i) < \prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (n - i)$$

This implies
$$\binom{m}{k} = \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (m - i) < \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (n - i) = \binom{n}{k}$$

So, what I've got is
$$\binom{m}{k} < \binom{n}{k}$$

Now, I am pretty much stuck. If $m < n$, then $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m}$, so
$$\frac{1}{n^k} < \frac{1}{m^k}$$

which would imply that

$$\frac{1}{n^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{m^k} \binom{n}{k}$$

So I guess I've messed something up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   write it as $\;
\displaystyle \frac{1}{k!}\,\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \,\left(1-\dfrac{i}{m}\right) \;\lt\; \frac{1}{k!}\,\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \,\left(1-\dfrac{i}{n}\right)\;$ and compare the terms.

Comment: But why is it that $1 - \frac{i}{m} < 1 - \frac{i}{n}$?

Comment: @PhysicsUndergraduateStudent Because $\frac{1}{n} \lt \frac{1}{m}$ (as you wrote in the post) $\implies \frac{i}{n} \lt \frac{i}{m}$ $\implies 1-\frac{i}{n} \gt 1-\frac{i}{m}$.

Comment: Ohh I see. But that leaves me wondering if my reasoning was correct as well, that is: Does $$\frac{1}{n^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{m^k} \binom{n}{k}$$ hold as well then?

Comment: @PhysicsUndergraduateStudent That holds as well, but it's a *weaker* inequality than asked, since: $$
\frac{1}{n^k} \binom{m}{k} < \color{red}{\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} < \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}} < \frac{1}{m^k} \binom{n}{k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$1-\frac j m < 1- \frac j n$ for $j=0,1,2,...,k-1$. Just multiply these inequalities and simplify.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't see why $1-\frac j m < 1- \frac j n$ holds if $m < n$

Comment: $1-\frac j x$ is an increasing function of $x$. An even simpler argument is $m <n$ implies $\frac 1 m > \frac 1 n$ which implies $\frac j m > \frac j n$ which in turn implies $1-\frac j m <1- \frac jn $